# Hash function to see if one string is scrambled form/permutation of another?

Tags: string, algorithm

I want to check if string A is just a reordered version of string B. For example, "abc" = "bca" = "cab"...

There are other solutions here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-strings-are-permutation-of-each-other/

However, I was thinking a hash function would be an easy way of doing this, but the typical hash function takes order into consideration. Are there any hash functions that do not care about character order?

Comment: No, that's not what hash functions are for.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that producing different hashes for elements in different order is precisely what hash functions need to do. If order is not important to you, sort before hashing.

Comment: I suggest the counting characters idea.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any hash functions that do not care about character order?

I don't know of real-world hash functions that have this property, no. Because this is not a problem they are designed to solve.

However, in this specific case, you can make your own "hash" function (a very very bad one) that will indeed ignore order: just sum ASCII codes of characters. This works due to the commutative property of addition (`a + b == b + a`)

```
def isAnagram(self,a,b):
    sum_a = 0
    sum_b = 0
    for c in a:
        sum_a += ord(c)
    for c in b:
        sum_b += ord(c)
    return sum_a == sum_b
```

To reiterate, this is absolutely a hack, that only happens to work because input strings are limited in content [in the judge system](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/anagram-1587115620/1) (only have lowercase ASCII characters and do not contain spaces). It will not work (reliably) on arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 1):

For a fast check you could use a kind af hash-funkction

Candidates are:

- xor all characters of a String
- add all characters of a String
- multiply all characters of a String (be careful might lead to overflow for large Strings)

If the hash-value is equal, it could still be a collision of two not 'equal' strings. So you still need to make a dedicated compare. (e.g. sort the characters of each string before comparing them).

Comment: All these still run in linear time, so they are not any faster than, say, counting chars. They do use less memory, though.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: You could not get faster than linear, because you need to read at least the hole string. But calculating 1 value and comparing it might be faster than createing an array ouf counters, and than compare all entries of this array.

Comment: It might even be so (however marginally). Except when you have to run the full check anyway. Then it's twice as much work.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev " Then it's twice as much work." is still O(n).  [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)